# How to find files with square brackets in the name

Tags: regex, linux, find

I'm trying to find some files with square brackets, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My files are named are this:

[ABC] test file.txt

Regexp I'm trying:

```
find . -iregex '\[abc\].*test.*'
```

That just doesn't seem to work for some reason. If i replace it with -

```
find . -iregex '.*abc.*test.*'
```

-it works fine. So the problem is with the square brackets. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matching square brackets is not a problem. Problem is matching the file's path. Remember find's output starts with `./` for the current path.

So this regex in your find command will work for you:

```
find . -iregex '\./\[abc\].*test.*'
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: I know about SO ettiquette, I just went to sleep soon after the problem was solved :p