# Find files with brackets in their names with -iwholename

Tags: unix, escaping, find, string-matching

I am trying to find arbitrary files which may contain, among other scary characters, [square brackets]. Since I'm using `-iwholename`, I assume `find` treats `-iwholename` arguments literally, but the following works only when the brackets are escaped.

```
 $ touch [aoeu]
 $ ls
    [aoeu]
 $ find ./ -type f -iwholename ./[AOEU]
 $ find ./ -type f -iwholename ./\\[AOEU\\]
    ./[aoeu]
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528197/how-to-find-files-with-square-brackets-in-the-name), but it's talking about regexes, which I am not trying to use. I was just experimenting a bit more; I also realize `find` is doing other things I don't expect:

```
 $ touch \*aoeu\*
 $ ls
[aoeu]  *aoeu*
 $ find ./ -type f -iwholename ./\*AOEU\*   # I don't expect this expansion.
./*aoeu*
./[aoeu]
 $ find ./ -type f -iwholename ./\\\*AOEU\\\*            
./*aoeu*
```

How can I avoid, for **arbitrary** strings, this non-literal interpretation of some characters? Why does it happen?

EDIT:

Always good to read the 'effing manpage again. This time I found what I missed before:

```
  -iwholename pattern
          Like -wholename, but the match is case insensitive.

   -wholename pattern
          See -path.    This alternative is less portable than -path.

   -path pattern
          File name matches shell pattern pattern.  The metacharacters do not treat `/' or `.' specially; so, for example,
                    find . -path "./sr*sc"
          will print an entry for a directory called `./src/misc' (if one exists).  To ignore a whole directory tree, use -prune rather than checking every file in the tree.  For example, to skip the directory `src/emacs' and all files and directories under it, and print the names of the other files found, do something like this:
                    find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print
          Note that the pattern match test applies to the whole file name, starting from one of the start points named on the command line.  It would only make sense to use an absolute path name here if the relevant start point is also an absolute path.  This means that this command will never match anything:
                    find bar -path /foo/bar/myfile -print
          The predicate -path is also supported by HP-UX find and will be in a forthcoming version of the POSIX standard.
```

My "why" question is answered; now, as I said before, "How can I avoid, for **arbitrary** strings, this non-literal interpretation of some characters?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my `man find` page in BSD I see:

> ```
> -path pattern
>          True if the pathname being examined matches pattern.  Special
>          shell pattern matching characters (``['', ``]'', ``*'', and
>          ``?'') may be used as part of pattern.  These characters may be
>          matched explicitly by escaping them with a backslash (``\'').
>          Slashes (``/'') are treated as normal characters and do not have
>          to be matched explicitly.
> ```

(and `-path` is the same as `-wholename` and `-iwholename` is the same as `-path` but case insensitive)

You have to escape these characters because they have special meaning to the shell otherwise. This is the same for other flags like `-name` and `-iname`.

To make your `find` work with arbitrary strings, you need to escape these special characters, for example like this:

```
escaped=$(sed -e 's/[][?*]/\\&/g' <<< "*aoeu*")
find ./ -iwholename "$escaped"
```

**UPDATE**

As you yourself figured out, if you need to replace a lot of patterns per second, it will be more efficient to use `bash` to do the replacement instead of spawning a `sed` every time, like this:

```
filename_escaped="${filename//\[/\\[}"
filename_escaped="${filename_escaped//\]/\\]}"
filename_escaped="${filename_escaped//\*/\\*}"
filename_escaped="${filename_escaped//\?/\\?}"
```

Comment: Please address that I am talking about **arbitrary** strings. Should I go through my strings with something like `sed -e 's/[/\[/g' -e 's]/\]/g' -e 's/*/\*/g' -e 's/?/\?/g'`, or is there a better way of avoiding the pattern matching?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'll use bash to do the replacement instead since I don't want my whole script to depend on sed for this one little replacement... `filename_escaped="${filename//\[/\\[}" ; filename_escaped="${filename_escaped//\]/\\]}" ; filename_escaped="${filename_escaped//\*/\\*}" ; filename_escaped="${filename_escaped//\?/\\?}"`

Comment: @catlover2 hm, that's a pretty good idea. More efficient than spawning `sed`, especially if you have many patterns

Comment: I have a lot of them per second. ;)